# Infinitely countable subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be an infinite countable subspace.

Can $A$ be connected?

I have seen plenty of proofs that show that $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A$ is connected and I understand those.  However, none of them talk about whether $A$ is connected.

I would think it would be.  By the same logic as those other proofs here is my proof:

Let $x,y\in A$.  Now there are uncountably many paths from $x$ to $y$ in the plane.  Since $A$ is countable then there exists at least one path from x to y that would start at x, leave $A$, and come back to $A$ and end at $y$. (Paths will leave $A$)  However, I don't see how that would stop there from being a path from x to y in A.

There was another theorem that said let $X$ be Hausdorff and $A\subset X$ with $A$ connected, then $A$ contains 1 or infinitely many elements.

Now, I tried using this theorem (because $\mathbb{R}^2$ is Hausdorff), but my logic started to confuse me.

If $A$ is not connected, then I was going to use this theorem in my proof of contradiction.  So suppose $A$ is connected, then this theorem says $A$ has one or infinitely many points, but $A$ has infinitely many elements.  So, we have no contradiction.

And if we suppose $A$ is not connected, then we can't use this theorem because the assumptions are not met.

This Theorem might not even help us at all.

But please help me!

Comment: I've changed the tags, since I don't think "generalized topology" is appropriate.

Answer (score 7):

Any countable subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with at least two elements :P) is indeed disconnected; but I think it takes a different argument than what you sketch to show this.

Here's a proof outline. Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ be countable and fix distinct $a, a'\in A$. Say that a positive real $r$ is *good* if

- $r<d(a, a')$, and
- for no $b\in A$ do we have $d(a, b)=r$.

> **Exercise**: Since $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, there is some good $r$.

*This will use the fact that $d(a, a')>0$ - so in particular there are uncountably many positive reals less than $d(a, a')$.*

OK, let $r>0$ be good. Now consider $B_r(a)$, the ball of radius $r$ centered on $a$.

> **Exercise**: For each $b\in A\setminus B_r(a)$, there is some open ball $U_b\ni b$ with $U_b\cap B_r(a)=\emptyset$.

*This is where the goodness of $r$ is used.*

OK, now consider the two sets $$B_r(a)\quad\mbox{ and }\quad \bigcup_{b\in A\setminus B_r(a)} U_b.$$

> **Exercise**: these are nonempty open sets which are disjoint and cover $A$.

*Note that $a'\in \bigcup_{b\in A\setminus B_r(a)} U_b$.*

So $A$ is not connected.

---

"Hang on!" you might say, "This is a *topology* problem. Why drag a metric into things?"

There is indeed a way to write this argument without invoking a metric at all. Fix distinct $a, a'\in A$, $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ countable and nonempty. Then say that an open set $U$ is *good* if

- $U$ contains $a$ but not $a'$, and
- For every $b\in A$, either $b\in U$ or $b\not\in \overline{U}$ (where "$\overline{U}$" denotes the *closure* of $U$).

Then, we only need to show

> There is an uncountable family $U_i$ of open sets containing $a$ but not $a'$, which have disjoint boundaries.

Then a counting argument shows that there is a good open set, and the rest of the argument goes through unchanged.

Note, though, that the highlighted step above is easiest to do if we have the metric description of $\mathbb{R}^2$ at our disposal.

Comment: I really enjoyed this proof, but I'm not seeing how can we make sure that $A \not\subseteq B_r(a)$? I'm afraid that $\cup U_b$ at the end turns out to be empty.

Comment: @YuriThamsten Good eye - I assumed tacitly that $A$ was unbounded (so that whatever $r$ we pick, there is a $b\in A$ with $d(a, b)>r$). See my edit (in particular, we're guaranteed to have $a'\in \bigcup U_b$).

Comment: Really nice one!

Comment: Or just draw a continuum of lines, each intersecting the segment aa' and perpendicular to it. Pick one of those parallel lines which misses the set $A.$

Comment: @bof That works too - or indeed any family of uncountably-many disjoint sets not containing $a$ or $a'$ which split $\mathbb{R}^2$ into two open pieces.

Comment: . . . one of which contains $a$, the other of which contains $a'$. :P

Comment: By the way, this proof (or a simple variant thereof) shows more, namely $A$ is totally disconnected, meaning that each of its connected components is a single point.

Comment: That is neat, I never thought about it that way before.  Far better than clubbing it to death with  Urysohn's Lemma.